# Cleaner way of checking values of textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that lists items and has a quantity textbox column that starts with an initial value of 0.

```
item name | price | quantity
item1     | $1.00 |    0
item2     | $1.00 |    0
item3     | $1.00 |    0
```

I want to check if all of the rows have 0 as their value.

I'm currently thinking of using this:

```
var all_zeros = true;
$('input.item-quantity').each(function () {
    //Check for 0 quantity and update all_zeros var
}
```

Is there a cleaner and hopefully better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will help you:

```
var zeeroCount = $('input.item-quantity').filter(function(){
  return $(this).val() == "0";
}).length;

var allCount = $('input.item-quantity').length;

if(zeeroCount == allCount)
{
  ........
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
$('input.item-quantity[value="0"]').length;
```

Comment: Careful... `.filter` is not supported in IE <= 8.

Comment: @Stephen:- `$('input.item-quantity[value="0"]').length;` will work.

Comment: Yep.  I was looking for that when you posted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can short circuit.  Try this:

```
var all_zeros = true;

$('input.item-quantity').each(function () {
    return all_zeros = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) === 0;
});
console.log(all_zeros); // false
```

This way you can stop at the first encountered non-zero, instead of iterating over the entire list every time.

http://jsfiddle.net/E3uGD/

Answer (score 0):

That is probably the way I would approach it. Is there a reason you don't like it?

Comment: I did go with my original approach at first, but I felt there was a shorter way to do it.